# How do I create a combobox in active cell?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, combobox, basic

I want to create a script, that selects the first blank row, and then places a drop down in the "A" column of that row. I then want to use .additem("") to add the items that I need to it. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you create just one dropdown and then just hide it. You can easily change the items in the ComboBox using sheet events depending on your needs. You show it and adjust its location in the event as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub AddComboBox(Col As Long)
    Dim LastRow As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp)
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                                    Link:=False, _
                                    DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                                    Left:=0, _
                                    Top:=LastRow.Top + LastRow.Height, _
                                    Width:=100, _
                                    Height:=16)
        With .Object
            .AddItem "Hi"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

15 is the default row height. All bets are off when your rows have different heights.

**Edit 1**: As per your comment, you can use this as much as you want by calling it from another sub. I've added a parameter to the first sub called Col which is the Id of your column.

```
Sub Main()
Dim I As Long
For I = 1 To 3
AddComboBox I
Next
End Sub
```

**Edit 2:** I've incorporated dee's productive comment that handles variable rows height.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The macro is working, but it is only working once, how can I repeat it?

Comment: What do you mean repeat it?

Comment: More on ActiveX Controls here mate http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win002.htm if this has helped you please tick the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I would like to be able to insert this into the first blank row, then hit it again and do the same in the next blank row.  Thanks in advance

Comment: I've edit the code. Now; from your the Sub Main, you just need to indicate the end counter and the start counter `I`. The example above will add comboboxes to column A, B and C (three columns).

Comment: @JLILI Aman maybe ```LastRow ``` could be declared as ```Range``` and referenced like this ```Set LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp)```. Then the combo box could be added to exact position because the height of the last row can be retrieved from the ```LastRow```. Like this ```ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Top:=LastRow.Top + LastRow.Height, ...)```.

Comment: Thanks Dee. Just did that.